# .NET Core - Why do I get inconsistent output folder structure when using dotnet publish?

Tags: windows, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I use the following commands to publish my net core web api to a folder named "release".

Using `dotnet publish -o release` produces a `release, runtimes and wwwroot` folder followed by .exe files and dll:s. The folder structure produced by this command can be uploaded to my server and the api works as expected.

`dotnet publish -c Release -o release --self-contained true -r win-x86` does not produce these three folders but only the .exe files and dll:s. In this case when the folder structure is uploaded to my server the api does not work as expected, it seems like it cannot find the dotnet runtime.

What are the differences between these two cases? I expected the latter published folder structure to work like the first, only without publishing the reduntant additional runtimes.

I use dotnet version: 6.0.411

Comment: Which dotnet version are you using (`dotnet --version`)?

Answer (score 0):

Answering here because of the character limit.

- `runtimes` folder shouldn't show up because you're already specifying a runtime in your command (`win-x86`).
- I'm pretty sure a `release` folder shouldn't be there and you're only seeing it with the regular publish because you ran the other command with `-o release` before and the former just copied it over. Try removing it from your project directory and invoking the regular publish command again and let's see what happens, but chances are that's not your problem. I'd publish it to another directory, either outside of the projecct directory or inside of the `bin/` one.
- Chances are your issue 'only' has to do with `wwwroot` folder not being copied over. However, I haven't been able to reproduce that with either .NET 8 or .NET 6 (6.0.411) by creating a webapp using `dotnet new webapp -n TestOutput` and then publishing it using both commands. I'd suggest to copy your `.csproj` and your solution's `Directory.Build.props` file (if you have one) here, in case that helps us identifying anything weird there that affects the behavior of self-contained apps.